# VS2012 Designer Could Not Load Assembly

Tags: c#, user-interface, visual-studio-2012, desktop-application, windows-forms-designer

There is a solution with a C# project referencing a managed C++ library which in turn references a native C++ library. The C# project contains BaseUserControl and ChildUserControl which extends it.

The problem is: if code from the native C++ is called (via the managed C++ library) in the constructor of BaseUserControl then ChildUserControl can't be veiwed in the designer view; nor can you add either of BaseUserControl or ChildUserControl to a Form. We get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'TestLibCPP, Version=1.0.4877.30347,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

How can we fix this?

I have included a [simple VS2012 solution](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9Qc3MdJBVcnVE5DWDNFQWU4RWc/edit?usp=sharing) which demonstrates the problem. This is a contrived example based on a problem we are having with a large codebase which has recently been converted from VS2005 to VS2012.

Thanks

Comment: That's inevitable, Windows needs to be able to find that native DLL when the designer loads it.  Too few places it looks, storing it in a directory on the PATH would be required.  Very brittle.  Best to split the DLL in two.

Comment: Does anyone have an answer that does not involve 32 bit compilation?  I offered the bounty because we have a 64 bit application with this issue.  It is not an option to compile everything in 32 bit.

Comment: ups just saw the sub-question now ... why not simply change the c++ dlls than to x64. that way you can leave the C# part at any target. Tested it with the given example and it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

If you have the source code ,please try rebuild the solution using configuraion( X86 platform) and then try open the ChildUserControl with designer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem could be that your native dll is build on top of 32-bit configurations try building your project on 32-bit platform

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the GUITest platform target to x86. It is currently 'Any CPU'. You can do this regardless of if your on a 64 bit or 32 bit box. Be sure to review the plaforms in your configuration too (Debug, Release, ..)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is exactly based on the X86 architecture of your C++ projects. Your WinForms Project references "Any CPU".

I've included a picture to show you where to change it (sry it's in german but you should find it from the position on the screen :)

1. Right-click your Winforms project and go to settings
2. Switch to tab Compile (guess thats the english name for it)
3. Change target platform to x86
4. Build and have fun ;)

[image: How to change Target Platform]

EDIT:

I've just seen that the Bounty Question was regarding having everything setup to 64bit so to achieve that simply set the targets of the C++ dlls to x64 architecture.

1. Right click on any of the c++ DLLs and go to settings
2. in the upper area you will see a button called configuration-manager
3. in the newly opened window just set all C++ dlls to x64.
4. if its not available to select just click on the arrow and create a new x64 (not ARM) architecture for the second project disselect the "create new" checkbox and select the previously created one.

[image]